# How can I use `find` with `-pattern` and also restrict depth?

Tags: find, wildcards, path

This is as far as I've gotten:

```
find . -path \*/pages/*/index.css
```

Which will find:

```
./lib/pages/home/index.css
./lib/pages/home/lib/header/index.css
```

What I really want is to only find:

```
./lib/pages/home/index.css
```

While `/home/` could be anything, such as `/about/` or `/checkout/`

When I attempt to use the `-maxdepth` flag I get:

```
find: warning: you have specified the -maxdepth option after a non-option argument -path, but options are not positional (-maxdepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments.
```

Comment: See `-maxdepth` in `man find`.

Comment: sorry, I should have specified that I've tried `-maxdepth` but it's not available when using `-path`

Comment: Actually you were right, I was placing `-maxdepth` after `-path` but it should have come before.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to goldilocks for help, using `-maxdepth` solved my issues. The problem was that I was giving `-maxdepth` after `-path`. The following syntax works as expected:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -path \*/pages/*/index.css
```

Comment: Please don't post thanks as answers. Instead, if someone gave you the answer in a comment 1) ask them to post an answer which you can then [accept](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) or 2) post the answer yourself, but in such a way that someone else who reads your question will understand what is necessary to make it work. Also, please remember to accept it.